# PHP : soapCall with complex arguments

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to set up a SOAP connexion between a supplier and I in order to synchronize data between our databases. 
I've managed to connect him with a simple soapCall threw that php lines ($service is the name of the Soap function I'm reaching, and $data is an associative array that contains my variables) :

```
    $request = new SoapClient($client, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
    $response = $request->$service($data);
```

That lines work if my XML scheme of variables has no collections like in this example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <ServiceITryToReach xmlns="https://mysuplier:65100/">
        <Login>login</Login>
        <Password>pass</Password>
        <Variables>
          <Variable1>data</Variable1>
          <Variable2>data</Variable2>
        </Variables>
      </ServiceITryToReach>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In the example above, my associative array that contains my variables will be :

```
array('Login'=>'login','Password'=>'pass','Variables'=>array('Variable1'=>'data','Variable2'=>'data'));
```

**But, if my XML scheme contains collections of variables of same type, how can I represent it with an associative array in PHP ?**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
          <ServiceITryToReach xmlns="https://mysuplier:65100/">
            <Login>login</Login>
            <Password>pass</Password>
            <Variables>
              <Variable>
                 <data>data</data>
              </Variable>
              <Variable>
                 <data>data</data>
              </Variable>
              <Variable>
                 <data>data</data>
              </Variable>
            </Variables>
          </ServiceITryToReach>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

In conclusion, I'm looking for another simple way to request my supplier with multiple variables. The best would be to have **a direct XML input in my soapCall method instead of an associative array**. 
An idea ? 
Thanks, 
Nico